# Shapely (geos) crashes during unary_union

Tags: python, python-2.7, shapely, union, geos

When attempting to union multiple polygons with Shapely 1.5.6 in Python 2.7.9, using GEOS 3.4.2, I get the following error in the underlying C++ code:

```
Assertion failed: (!"should never be reached"), function itemsTree, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 371
```

The polygons are in a Python list and then I call `shapely.ops.unary_union(polygon_list)`.  The polygon list has 1998 items, all of which are proper polygons.  I have tried running the `unary_union` operation in a separate python session with a couple manually created polygons and it works.

Could the number of polygons be a problem, or the import order in the file (I have seen a mention of shapely needing to be imported before Basemap, but I am not using that package)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own after testing some rearranging of import statements.  In my case, `rasterio` needed to be imported **after** shapely.

For example:

```
import shapely
import rasterio
```

Comment: Shapely and Rasterio shouldn't be sensitive to import order. Where are you getting the software from? PyPI or http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ or elsewhere?

Comment: I installed both packages from PyPi using pip install ...
I am using a Mac with OS X 10.9, python installed via MacPorts

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue with Shapely 1.5.7, installed on my mac via the wheel available on the [shapely PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely).  The solution for me was to:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-use-wheel shapely
```

After recompiling, Shapely worked as expected.

I'm on a mac (OS 10.10.2), with geospatial dependencies (including GEOS) installed via [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: See https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/262 for the resolution of this issue.